# Ruby on Rails Devise Select Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I added a select tag in the registration view with 2 options

```
<div>
    <select name="typ">
      <option value="0">
        Musiker
      </option>
      <option value="1">
        Veranstalter
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And i add a colum to the Database

```
class AddTypToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :typ, :integer
  end
end
```

How can i save the value of the select in the Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to add the new parameter to the strong_parameter sanitization of devise. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

In your `ApplicationController`

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:typ])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise allows you to save additional fields on registration. Read [their documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), particularly the section on strong parameters.